# shortcut to find out the references of the properties file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a java project in which I am making changes in one of the properties files. I am using eclipse juno for my development, now I want an eclipse shortcut from which I can know that the properites file is being used internally in which different java files.

I know that one way is to press ctrl + h and in file search typing the name of the file and in type selecting the .java extension. My query is that is there any other shortcut to know that where this properties file is called internally in different java files 
 .

Comment: Control + Click the name of property in the property file, it will show you all references.

Comment: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a built-in command for getting the references of an entry in a property file. The type hierarchy and the "Control + Click"-thing works because the java sources can be interpreted to get actual calls. For accesses to .property files this is not as easy as there are several ways to access them for example.

That's why there sometimes a pattern is used where the properties are only accessed by exactly one Java class. This class then provides the properties as static fields for example. Doing this the compiler helps you in getting the references.